# Formulating a problem as a linear program

Tags: linear-programming, word-problem, integer-programming, operations-research

I have the following problem:

> I want to sell five computers. Denote them by $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. I am allowed to take offers for subsets of the five computers. Three buyers, $A$, $B$, and $C$, want to make an offer. Each buyer has identified a maximum price that they would be willing to pay for various combinations: each individual buyer would only buy at most one parcel combination. 
>  What is a possible linear programming formulation if I want to maximize the money that I make?

---

I would appreciate any help in approaching this problem.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few hints.

Define a binary variable for each combination.  The objective is to maximize revenue.  Two sets of constraints: don't sell the same computer more than once, and don't sell more than one combination to the same buyer.

Comment: Correct so far.  Now consider each computer one at a time.  Which variables involve computer 1?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.